# weak convergence in L_p spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

for $u_k\in L_p(\Omega)$

if I know that $\int_{\Omega'}|u_k|^p\to0$ for every subset $\Omega'\subset\Omega$ s.t 
$ dist(\Omega',\partial \Omega) >0$

and I know that $\int_{\Omega}|u_k|^p$ is uniformly bounded how can I prove that $u_k\to 0$ weakly to 0 in $L_p(\Omega)$

thank you

Comment: What is $\Omega$?  Tryss's proof is OK if $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: You're right, I made this assumtion without explicitely mentioning it, I'll will add this precision in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for $v\in L^q$, you have

$$ \left| \int_\Omega vu_k \right| \leq \left| \int_{\Omega'} vu_k \right| + \left| \int_{\Omega\setminus \Omega'} vu_k \right| $$

$$\leq \|v\|_{q,\Omega'}\|u_k\|_{p,\Omega'}+\|v\|_{q,\Omega\setminus \Omega'}\|u_k\|_{p,\Omega\setminus \Omega'}$$

The first part converge to 0, and the second part is less than

$$\left( \int_\Omega |u_k|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\left( \int_{\Omega\setminus \Omega'} |v|^q \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$

And as the first term is bounded, you get

$$\leq M\left( \int_{\Omega\setminus \Omega'} |v|^q \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$

And By Lebesgue theorem, this converge to 0